# How to make my homemade program not come up with security warnings?

Tags: certificates, malware, code-signing

I am an amateur developer and trying to make a exe file for windows that can be downloaded from the internet, or sent to my colleagues via email, but whenever it's opened it comes up with two warnings on my machine. The first is the standard windows warning, do not open random exe files from the internet, and the second is Norton security.

There seem to be these issues:

- It doesn't have a digital certification.
- Unknown publisher, internet origin.
- Originated very recently.
- Very few downloads (in the Norton community).

How can I stop these things from discouraging me from running the program? The program does nothing malevolent, not remotely. Do I need to buy some kind of certificate?

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Install your own root certificate to the system's certificate store, this is only suitable for programs you use for yourself or a small number of users, and doesn't cost you anything
2. Get a code signing certificate from a trusted Certificate Authority. You need either a registered business or legal proof identity for most CA to approve your application

References:

1. [Introduction to Code Signing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537361(v=vs.85).aspx)
2. Find a Certificate Authority [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/documents/2592.windows-root-certificate-program-members-list-all-cas.aspx) or [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31634.microsoft-trusted-root-certificate-program-participants.aspx)

Comment: This seems to only adresses the missing certification part. Will this also solve the Norton Community errors?